# python pandas not concat'ing into empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I'm iterating over a `DataFrame`, evaluating each row and then sticking it into another `DataFrame` by using the `concat()` method. However, the receiving `DataFrame` is still empty.

```
import pandas as pd

empty = DataFrame(columns=('col1', 'col2'))

d = {'col1' : Series([1, 2, 3]),
    'col2' : Series([3, 4, 5])
}

some_data = DataFrame(d)

print empty
print some_data
print 'concat should happen below'

for index, row in some_data.iterrows():
    pd.concat([empty, DataFrame(row)])

print empty # should contain 3 rows of data
```

OUTPUT:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     3     5
concat should happen below
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2]
Index: []
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I've got a dataset that includes timestamps that correspond to different analytic event states, such as start and end states and across different contexts. I'd like to compute the time between a start and end state after validating that the start and end state are from the same context and belong to the same session.

Comment: The way I've been thinking about this was to create multiple `DataFrame`s that each contain a distinct context to make computing values in them easier. I won't need to look across contexts (data from users doing this thing vs. that other thing), only within each context.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a groupby, difficult to answer without more info (but perhaps that should be a separate question). What I meant was you shouldn't create an empty DataFrame **or** concat with an iterrows (just concat, or join/merge)... ATM this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4):

You need to update `empty` if you want it to stores the values: `empty = pd.concat([empty, DataFrame(row)])`
Also you can concatenate the whole `DataFrame`s, try this `print pd.concat([ empty,some_data])`

If you want to filter the rows you can try this:

```
def f(r):
    #check the row here
    return True #returns True or False if include/exclude the row

print some_data.groupby(some_data.index).filter(f)
```

Comment: I want to `concat` a row, because I'm validating it before putting it into the new `DataFrame`. For this reason I also can't reassign `empty` on each `for` loop.

Without explicitly calling `DataFrame(row)`, I'll get a `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_data''

Comment: Ah, ok. I do that using `groupby` and `filter`. Updated the answer.